# Отличия FileBody от InputStreamBody

Tags: java, httpclient

Есть файл большого размера. Если использую `FileBody`, то всё работает нормально.

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(); 
entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(file)); 
post.setEntity(entity); 
client.execute(post);
```

А если использую `InputStreamBody`, то файл на сервер не загружается.

```
entity.addPart("file", new InputStreamBody(new FileInputStream(file), name) { 
  @Override 
  public long getContentLength() { 
    size; 
  } 
});
```

В чем их отличие? И как загрузить файл, используя `InputStreamBody`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У `FilBody` метод длина контента (метод `getContentLenght`) равна размеру файла. А у `InputStreamBody` она равна -1. В классе `MultipartEntity` определяется, является ли он повторяемым (repeatable) таким образом: если имеется хоть одна повторяемая часть, то и entity также repeatable. Свойство repeatable означает, что сущность может быть прочитана несколько раз. Таким образом, логично, что повторяемым является только `FileBody`.

Но просто переопределить `getContentLenght` и возвращать реальную длину вместо -1 нельзя. Потому что тогда у вас возникнет исключение:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException 
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:557) 
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487) 
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465) 
    at it.sella.iq.Main.main(Main.java:63) 
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.NonRepeatableRequestException: 
Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity 
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:402) 
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555) 
    ... 3 more
```

Если открыть реализацию метода `writeTo` в `InputStreamBody`, можно увидеть:

```
@Override
public void writeTo(final OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    if (out == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Output stream may not be null");
    }
    try {
        byte[] tmp = new byte[4096];
        int l;
        while ((l = this.in.read(tmp)) != -1) {
            out.write(tmp, 0, l);
        }
        out.flush();
    } finally {
        this.in.close();
    }
}
```

А в `FileBody`:

```
@Override
public void writeTo(final OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    if (out == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Output stream may not be null");
    }
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(this.file);
    try {
        byte[] tmp = new byte[4096];
        int l;
        while ((l = in.read(tmp)) != -1) {
            out.write(tmp, 0, l);
        }
        out.flush();
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

То есть при первой же попытке поток закрывается.

Если хотите иметь repeatable аналог `InputStreamBody`, не забудьте переопределить и метод `writeTo` по образцу `FileBody` (каждый раз открывать новый поток, а в поле класса хранить, например, массив байтов).